# Join table multiple times to another table that may or may not have those values

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have three tables:

```
| items
--------
id
quantity
size_attribute_value_id
color_attribute_value_id
type_attribute_value_id

| attribute_values (instance of an attribute, like red, xsmall)
--------
id
attribute_id
name

| attributes (attribute category, like color, size)
id
name
```

Any combination of the three attributes (size, color, type) can make a valid item. Therefore, I want to be able to query for all combinations of the three attributes, while also including already existing items from the items table. The idea being I want a result set of all existing items and all possible valid future items. For example, even if the items table is completely blank, I should still get results of non-existent but valid items with quantities of 0.

Valid attribute_ids are 1, 2, 4.

I've tried the following right join as a start:

```
SELECT i.*, av1.*, av2.*, av3.*
FROM items i 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN attribute_values av1 ON av1.attribute_id = 2 AND av1.id = i.size_attribute_value_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN attribute_values av2 ON av2.attribute_id = 4 AND av2.id = i.color_attribute_value_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN attribute_values av3 ON av3.attribute_id = 1 AND av3.id = i.type_attribute_value_id;
```

But it's only returning about 200 rows, when it should be more over 1000.

Any help, even if just a point in the right direction, is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a1.name as `type`, a2.name as `size`, a4.name as `color`, SUM(COALESCE( i.quantity , 0 ) ) as quantity
FROM (attribute_values a1, attribute_values a2, attribute_values a4)
LEFT JOIN items i
ON i.type_attribute_value_id = a1.id
AND i.size_attribute_value_id = a2.id
AND i.color_attribute_value_id = a4.id
WHERE a1.attribute_id = 1 AND a2.attribute_id = 2 AND a4.attribute_id = 4
GROUP BY a1.name, a2.name, a4.name
```

This assumes you have also a lot of other attributes other than type, size and color and possibly more columns in your items table, if you don't it would be much better to put attributes in separate tables, like types, colors and sizes, which would be easier to query and give you noticeable performance improvement with proper indexing when your database grows big.

Comment: There are other columns, but in this case, an 'item' can only have those three attributes. Other parts of the system use an attributes_to_X table. Rewriting this attributes system is definitely something I've thought a lot about...

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it -

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM attribute_values WHERE attribute_id = 4) AS `color`
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM attribute_values WHERE attribute_id = 2) AS `size`
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM attribute_values WHERE attribute_id = 1) AS `type`
LEFT JOIN items
    ON `color`.`id` = `items`.`color_attribute_value_id`
    AND `size`.`id` = `items`.`size_attribute_value_id`
    AND `type`.`id` = `items`.`type_attribute_value_id`
```

I have rewritten this query to avoid the derived tables. It should perform better.

```
SELECT color.name, size.name, type.name, IFNULL(items.quantity, 0) AS quantity
FROM attribute_values AS `color`
INNER JOIN attribute_values AS `size`
    ON size.attribute_id = 2
INNER JOIN attribute_values AS `type`
    ON type.attribute_id = 1
LEFT JOIN items
    ON `color`.`id` = `items`.`color_attribute_value_id`
    AND `size`.`id` = `items`.`size_attribute_value_id`
    AND `type`.`id` = `items`.`type_attribute_value_id`
WHERE color.attribute_id = 4;
```

Comment: Wow, that appears to do it! I'm going to investigate more before declaring this the answer.

Comment: You're right, in that the second query performs much better! While this answer gives me good data, @piotrm's answer's use of coalesce returns a better structure.

Comment: My example does the same thing but without the additional overhead of the GROUP BY clause. Assuming that there can only be zero or one row in the items table for a given combination of attributes the GROUP BY clause serves no purpose.